# Rover Mini Mayfair Auto 1990/H

Tags: ignition, timing, distributor, rover

When cranking, the engine turns and there is a spark....not strong.  I can't find the timing mark through the circulled(rubber) hole, but the arrow shows on the cover.

***How can I freely turn (by hand) the pulley?***

It is absolutely STIFF, the fan is slipping.  I think I must have messed around with the timing totally.

New breaker points and distributor

Please advice ASAP.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Messed with the timing as in the distributor is out of whack, or were you actually messing with the timing chain or something else you didn't mention?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can turn the crankshaft via its pulley.

But this is probably easier. If you want to turn the crankshaft by hand you can use a socket with a long handle / breaker bar on it to "Tighten" the bolt on the end of the engine crankshaft. Usually that bolt holds the harmonic dampener.  Be careful here as if the crankshaft gets stiff you might exceed install torque for that bolt. Go SLOW.  When you go slow, a bit of the compression will leak around the piston rings.

Don't forget you will be fighting cylinder compression when you do this, so go slow.  If you need to do this on a repeated basis, you could remove the spark plugs, the force will got to nearly nothing.

Comment: Thanks mate, I have not touch the timing chain, only the dizzy has been moved!
Fitted new contact breaker/condenser that's all I did but the car was started or running over 4 years lots of condensation built up, some one advised me start from the scratch by Timing through crank shaft arrow lined up, then rotor arm pointing to cylinder 1, I have done every thing apart from unable to move crank or finding the 'o' marking on the fly wheel. Please please Help me. Cheers

Comment: have you removed all the sparkplugs and hand turned the engine to find the timing mark.  removing the sparkplugs is what makes it easy to turn over.